# Android bitmap quality issues

Tags: android, bitmap

In my app, the bitmap is drawn as if the color is some lower quality type. If i load up the background image using the gallery app, it loads just fine and does not look like it's super low quality. The code i am using to load and draw my images is simple:

```
//Code for initializing the Bitmap
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.none), (int) (canvas.getWidth() * compression), (int) (canvas.getHeight() * compression), true);
//...
//Code for drawing this Bitmap
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, new RectF(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight()), null);
```

If nothing in the code tells you what is wrong, i made an image comparing what the image actually looks like on a computer or other image viewer, and what it looks like in the app.
[image: Top image is the app on the phone, bottom image is what the background image actually looks like. Notice the lines on the top image. What is up with that?]

Comment: frankly, the graphics output of most android being par to crap, i'm not sure if users would complain..

Comment: @ina maybe it's crap because people accept half-assed solutions in their app ;).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

question  is somewhat similar to [Bad image quality after resizing/scaling bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821488/bad-image-quality-after-resizing-scaling-bitmap)

try disabling scaling, resize in an offscreen bitmap and make sure that Bitmap is 32 bits (ARGB888):

```
Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inScaled = false;
options.inDither = false;
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap source = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(a.getResources(), path, options);
```

another good and complete answer about image scaling/processing can be found at [Quality problems when resizing an image at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231817/quality-problems-when-resizing-an-image-at-runtime)

Comment: pls tell me what is "a.getResources()" a=?

Comment: activity::getResources()