# Bad image quality after picking an image from gallery

Tags: android

I use this to let the user pick an image from gallery:

```
Intent i = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                i.setType("image/*");
                i.putExtra("crop", "true");
                i.putExtra("scale", true);
                i.putExtra("return-data", true);
                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

Then it will be displayed in an ImageView:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

            final Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);

        }
    }
```

It works but the picture now has a bad quality.
How to fix this?

Comment: Likely get's botched in the compression during parceling. Or scaling gets thrown off. There are a few posts pertaining to scaling: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568188/android-bitmap-quality-issues or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821488/bad-image-quality-after-resizing-scaling-bitmap

Comment: What `scaleType` are you using on your ImageView?

Comment: I'm using `centerCrop`

Comment: Have you tried removing the scale and crop extras?

Comment: Did you try removing `i.putExtra("crop", "true");` and `i.putExtra("scale", true);` ?

Comment: Without the extras it works fine, the problem is the user should be able to resize the picture.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't specify any of those extras because they are device-dependent.  Just do this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

and

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        //load Uri into ImageView
    }
}
```

I would look into using a library like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) to load the images instead of just doing `imageView.setImageBitmap(photo)` if your app is image intensive.

Comment: Without the extras it works fine, the problem is the user should be able to resize the picture. Thanks for the library by the way.

Comment: Well the source of your problem is that you're being returned a thumbnail, which you're probably sizing up to fit the imageview, which is why the quality looks bad.  If you set the ImageView's size parameters to be `wrap_content` you'll see that you're receiving a thumbnail.  I'm not sure how to fix that issue as I've never used the pick intent with crop/size parameters before, sorry.