# android-bitmap low quality issue

Tags: java, android, xml, bitmap

I just created some functions to take picture from camera and put the result image into the imageview. And what i found is that my taken picture quality is so bad.

Here are some codes:

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            picture.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
    }

View.OnClickListener camerabtnlistener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
    };


@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_help_3);
        btnPicture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPicture);
        picture= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picture);
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        layoutPic = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutPic);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        btnPicture.setOnClickListener(camerabtnlistener);

    }
```

and the xml

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/picture"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/test_admin_big"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

i already tried these solution below, but that's not working

1. [Resizing ImageView to fit to aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400113/resizing-imageview-to-fit-to-aspect-ratio)
2. [Fit image into ImageView, keep aspect ratio and then resize ImageView to image dimensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232608/fit-image-into-imageview-keep-aspect-ratio-and-then-resize-imageview-to-image-d)
3. [Android bitmap quality issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568188/android-bitmap-quality-issues)

please advise

thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use Bundle extras = data.getExtras(); in your onActivityResult then it will return thumbnail image not actual image.

Here is code I have used for Capturing and Saving Camera Image then display it to imageview.

You have to save Camera image to specific location then fetch from that location.

Here is method for opening capturing camera image activity.

```
private static final int CAMERA_PHOTO = 111;
private Uri imageToUploadUri;

private void captureCameraImage() {
        Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "POST_IMAGE.jpg");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
        imageToUploadUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, CAMERA_PHOTO);
    }
```

then your onActivityResult() method should be like this.

```
  @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == CAMERA_PHOTO && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if(imageToUploadUri != null){
                    Uri selectedImage = imageToUploadUri;
                    getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
                    Bitmap reducedSizeBitmap = getBitmap(imageToUploadUri.getPath());
                    if(reducedSizeBitmap != null){
                        imageview.setImageBitmap(reducedSizeBitmap);
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(this,"Error while capturing Image",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Error while capturing Image",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } 
        }
```

Here is getBitmap() method used in onActivityResult().

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(String path) {

        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            final int IMAGE_MAX_SIZE = 1200000; // 1.2MP
            in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o);
            in.close();


            int scale = 1;
            while ((o.outWidth * o.outHeight) * (1 / Math.pow(scale, 2)) >
                    IMAGE_MAX_SIZE) {
                scale++;
            }
            Log.d("", "scale = " + scale + ", orig-width: " + o.outWidth + ", orig-height: " + o.outHeight);

            Bitmap b = null;
            in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            if (scale > 1) {
                scale--;
                // scale to max possible inSampleSize that still yields an image
                // larger than target
                o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o.inSampleSize = scale;
                b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o);

                // resize to desired dimensions
                int height = b.getHeight();
                int width = b.getWidth();
                Log.d("", "1th scale operation dimenions - width: " + width + ", height: " + height);

                double y = Math.sqrt(IMAGE_MAX_SIZE
                        / (((double) width) / height));
                double x = (y / height) * width;

                Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, (int) x,
                        (int) y, true);
                b.recycle();
                b = scaledBitmap;

                System.gc();
            } else {
                b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            }
            in.close();

            Log.d("", "bitmap size - width: " + b.getWidth() + ", height: " +
                    b.getHeight());
            return b;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("", e.getMessage(), e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: thanks, i now know that i used thumbnails to be shown at imageview,so i use actual image like you suggested. thank you

Comment: There is an error with this : Failed to find provider  for user 0; expected to find a valid ContentProvider for this authority

Answer (score 0):

instead of this simply create your own folder & give its uri while creating intent for camera eg:
               `Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                fileUri = GetOutpoutMediaFileUri.getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0)`