# How to get high quality/full image and put in imageview?

Tags: android, image

How can I get high quality image? Yes I already read some *"same question"* that's why I know that bitmap `data` is only a thumbnail and I already tried the answers but I have output problems.

Below are the output problems encountered and what source where I got the answer I tried.

[shows nothing on imageview:]

1) https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics

```
-setPic() code placed on onAcitivityResult
-Logcat Error on : Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this,"com.example.android.fileprovider", photoFile);
```

2) https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap

3) [android-bitmap low quality issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32066932/android-bitmap-low-quality-issue) (shows Toast message from)

```
if(reducedSizeBitmap != null){
    im1.setImageBitmap(reducedSizeBitmap);
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this,"Error while capturing Image 1",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

[crash/literally restarts phone after confirmation(after capturing):]

1) [Android Camera Intent: how to get full sized photo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448856/android-camera-intent-how-to-get-full-sized-photo?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] for your scenario #1. This would include how you are handling the result and trying to populate an `ImageView`. FWIW, [here is a complete sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.11/Camera/FileProvider) showing how to use `FileProvider` with `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`.

Comment: I just inserted the answers on my app to try. for nothing:#1 I inserted the setPic() code to the onActivityResult instead of creating another function. App is running and taking picture but nothing shows and have Logcat error. for crash#1 i get no error but once i clicked OK after the confirmation after capturing my phone restarts.

tried to insert the fileprovider on manifest but i have error/red "@xml/provider_paths". im still trying to debug it.