# Losing bitmap image quality

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I'm getting an image from gallery into a layout , then I'm getting the bitmap of that layout by using getBitmap(), after getting bitmap I'm saving the image into device storage by using saveImage().

After getting bitmap and saving the bitmap, the quality and pixel of that bitmap reduces too much as shown in the picture[Saved image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xm2Re.jpg) AND [Orignal image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7Gvo.jpg)

Here is the code for getting and saving bitmap

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(View v) {
    v.clearFocus();
    v.setPressed(false);

    boolean willNotCache = v.willNotCacheDrawing();
    v.setWillNotCacheDrawing(false);


    int color = v.getDrawingCacheBackgroundColor();
    v.setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor(0);

    if (color != 0) {
        v.destroyDrawingCache();
    }
    v.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap cacheBitmap = v.getDrawingCache();
    if (cacheBitmap == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return null;
    }

    Bitmap lastimage = Bitmap.createBitmap(cacheBitmap);

    v.destroyDrawingCache();
    v.setWillNotCacheDrawing(willNotCache);
    v.setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor(color);

    //2048x2048 resolution
    int newWidth = 2048;
    int newHeight = 2048;

    int width = lastimage.getWidth();
    int height = lastimage.getHeight();
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(lastimage, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);
    lastimage.recycle();

    saveImage(resizedBitmap);

    return resizedBitmap;

}
```

For Saving:

```
 private void saveImage (Bitmap finalBitmap) {
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/NewFolder");
    myDir.mkdirs();
    String fname = "Image-.png";
    File file = new File(myDir, fname);
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks for anyone's help.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [android-bitmap-quality-issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568188/android-bitmap-quality-issues)

Comment: How can i fix that?Can you explain please?

Comment: Why is that code encoding as PNG but claiming the file type is JPEG? Also, have you tried saving it *without* resizing the image beforehand?

Comment: Bymistake i write the file name as jpg. Yes i've tried but then the large size image is not saving

Comment: Can anyone know what should i do to maintain its quality??