# Android: How to solve a bitmap smoothing problem?

Tags: java, android, image, android-studio

I'm trying to draw an image on surface view, but it seems not to have the same quality as an original image. I'm doing it the following way:

```
mBackgroundBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mResources, R.drawable.background);
canvas.drawBitmap(mBackgroundBitmap , null, new Rect(0, 0, surfaceSize.mWidth, surfaceSize.mHeight), null);
```

Where `R.drawable.background` is a BMP image

This is how it looks in the default Android viewer:
[image]

And in my app:
[image]

Any ideas how to do the same quality as on the first picture?

Comment: You can try with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568188/android-bitmap-quality-issues

Comment: Have tried, still not working. Image size is 400x400 and surface size is 810x810, but scaling is not smooth enough

Comment: have you tried with Picasso or Glide?? you can load image as Uri instead of bitmap. try with Picasso from here https://guides.codepath.com/android/Displaying-Images-with-the-Picasso-Library

Comment: I wouldn't like to use any 3rdparty libs, I hope it is possible to do it with standard facilities

Comment: what is scaletype in imageview? try with changing that to fitXY or other scales. maybe helps