# OutOfMemoryError when loading my gridview with images

Tags: android, memory, gridview

having trouble with handling a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget error. The original pictures are never bigger then 250x250px. and loaded from the drawable folder. I found some solutions across the internet talking about 'inJustDecodeBounds' but I just can't get it to work.. Any ideas on how to fix this issue? It's causing me a headache for two days now...

Right now I am rescaling the image by a factor which I calculate based on the parent width..

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
        View mView = v;
        this.parent = parent;

        if (mView == null) {

            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            mView = vi.inflate(R.layout.caa_xml, null);
        }

        ImageView image = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.iv_caarow);

        String name = getItem(position).getFile();
        int resId = C.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable",
                "com.test.com");
        int imageWidth = (int) calculateImageWidth();
        // load the origial BitMap (250 x 250 px)
        Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory
                .decodeResource(C.getResources(), resId);

        int width = bitmapOrg.getWidth();
        int height = bitmapOrg.getHeight();
        int newWidth = imageWidth;
        int newHeight = imageWidth;

        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

        // create a matrix for the manipulation
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        // resize 
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
        // recreate the new Bitmap
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, 0, 0, width,
                height, matrix, true);

        BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(resizedBitmap);

        image.setImageDrawable(bmd);

        if (mView != null) {

            //additional code here

        }
        return mView;
    }

    private float calculateImageWidth() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int parentW = parent.getWidth() - parent.getPaddingLeft()
                - parent.getPaddingRight();
        Resources r = C.getResources();
        float pxPaddingBetweenItem = TypedValue.applyDimension(
                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 2, r.getDisplayMetrics());
        float pxPaddingInItem = TypedValue.applyDimension(
                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10, r.getDisplayMetrics());

        int totalImageWidth = (parentW - (int) (3 * pxPaddingBetweenItem) - (int) (8 * pxPaddingInItem)) / 4;
        float imageWidth = (float) totalImageWidth;
        return imageWidth;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is, that you create a scaled Bitmap by using the old big one. After that you have two Bitmaps in your Memory and you don't even recycle the old one.

Anyway, there is a better way:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.some_id);
String pathToImage = "path";

BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathToImage, bmOptions);
int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

// Determine how much to scale down the image
int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/50, photoH/50);

// Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathToFile, bmOptions);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

**Edit:**

When you want to use a resource Id instead of the file path, use [decodeResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeResource%28android.content.res.Resources,%20int,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options%29) and do the last part like this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resourceId, bmOptions);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Hope that piece of code helps you out!

Comment: Thanks Chris! Just one question, the path, do I need to get it in a string? Or is it possible to get this with int resId = C.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable",
    "com.test.com"); and to use decodeFile(resId, ...)?

Comment: Edited my post - hope that helps you out! If yes, please mark the post as correct answer, it's Christmas ;)

Comment: Hey Chris, I sure will do that ;) It works now! I only have a big quality loss.. especially the edges with this method.. I found on SA that adding bmOptions.inScaled = false;
  bmOptions.inDither = false;
  bmOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888; would solve this, but it doens't ... :s

Comment: Thanks, if this [thread] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231817/quality-problems-when-resizing-an-image-at-runtime) doesn't help, you're Images might just don't look well when you scale them down - try it out in Photoshop...

Comment: Sorry but, am I not having my original code again then? It's not much difference.. thanks for the help so far!