# Share image of views from a high dpi device to facebook

Tags: android, facebook, bitmap, image-scaling

I am having issues with sharing an image to Facebook that I create from my views in my app with high dpi devices. There are about 7 different statistic views that I put together to 2 column layout in a bitmap.

The problem is that Facebook [(src)](https://www.facebook.com/help/266520536764594) automatically resized images with a width of more than 960px to 960px max (the only exception is when the user uploads to a album with high quality option, but I'd rather not rely on that)

With a 1080p device the width of the created image about 2500px. If I upload that picture to Facebook it gets rescaled from Facebook and the text is impossible to read.

So I tried several ways to rescale my bitmap to fit into a width of 960px. I have tried [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231817/quality-problems-when-resizing-an-image-at-runtime), drawing the bitmap on a scaled canvas or the createScaledBitmap function but the text is always blurry. Is there anything else I can try? Or is there a better way to do this?