# Image becoming unrecognizable

Tags: android, image, bitmap

**Steps my application performs:-**

1. Download a large no of images and save them on the SDCard.
2. Load every image into Bitmap and resize them, after resizing replace this resized image with the original one.

**My code:-**

```
Bitmap myimage = loadimage(path+temppos+".jpg");
Bitmap finalimage = getResizedBitmap(myimage,width,height);
//save image 
.....
//recyclebitmap 
myimage.recycle();
finalimage.recycle();
```

**loadimage:-**

```
public Bitmap loadimage(String path)
    {

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
        options.inDither=true;
        options.inPurgeable=true;
        options.inInputShareable=true;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
    }
```

Now I' populating these images on gridview.

**Output(Before):-**
[image]

**Output (After):-**
[image]

Where `Before` corresponds to initially when only a few images are downloaded.
And `After` corresponds to after all the images are downloaded.

Now, I think it is happening maybe because of `Bitmap.recycle()` method but don't know the reason. Please correct me if I am wrong and point out the error here.

Edit: I must add the grid view shows around 50 downloaded images, but only the first three images are becoming unrecognizable.

Thanks.

Comment: would you please try `options.inSampleSize=3` before `decodeFile`. maybe you have memory problem.

Comment: JPEG is a **LOSSY** compression format. Each time you resave an image, it **looses details**. Also this: `options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;` **lowers the available colors** (16 bit).

Comment: @HBizhi Tried it. Getting the same problem. I checked the downloaded images, and the first 3 images are unrecognizable. They are saved as they are shown in the after output.

Comment: @Der Golem yeah bit I am performing the same operations on all the images then why only the first three images are distorting.

Comment: MAybe the other ones are **better quality** (lower compression) in the beginning. The ones distorting might be **lower quality** (higher compression). Try to temporarily rename the non distorting ones to the names of the distorting ones, to see that they won't be distorted.

Comment: I will try it. But I have 5 list of 50 image urls and whenever I change the urls, only the first 2-3 images are showing this problem, can't be a coincidence that only the first few images are always of lower quality.

Answer (score 0):

For getting your resized Bitmap you can use the below code: (taken from [this](http://sunil-android.blogspot.in/2013/08/out-of-memory-exception-during-decode.html) tutorial)

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromPath(String path, int reqWidth,
            int reqHeight) {

        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
                reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
        return bmp;
        }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
            int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
            if (width > height) {
                inSampleSize = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
            } else {
                inSampleSize = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
             }
         }
         return inSampleSize;
        }
```

You can also take a look at the [official site](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) for getting a hint on loading Bitmaps

**Edit**

Try to change bitmap configuration to [ARGB_8888](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html#ARGB_8888) for best quality

because RGB_565 configuration can produce slight visual artifacts depending on the configuration of the source (taken from [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html#RGB_565))

**Update**

I think you can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4250279) , I think this would solve your problem

Comment: My code for resizing is working perfectly. My problem is with the image distortion happening to the first few downloaded images.

Comment: Tried it, no changes. I think the problem is due to improper handling of `bitmap.recycle()` method

Comment: can you add your save bitmap function?

Comment: @Mohit Meanwhile I've updated my answer ,plz take a look

Comment: I am using download manager. So it just consists of a few lines. `request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(....)` after initializing `DownloadManager` and `Request`

Comment: Nope. I am already using all the methods the questions does, in my application  I am downloading a total of 50 images but only the first few images are distorting.

Comment: Have you tried to remove these 
        options.inPurgeable=true;
        options.inInputShareable=true; and test?

Comment: I fixed the problem. It was because I was resizing the image to a lower resolution then they were. But why the only first few were distorting, I am still unable to understand.