# Bitmaps from Gallery are blurred and jaggered

Tags: android, image, bitmap, byte

I'm currently working on an application which requires users to upload a photo to the app from their gallery.

I've looked at a number of solutions including coming up with my own. However, I can't figure out why the ImageView, taking in the final Bitmap is blurred & the edges are jaggered.

As an example, I'm currently using this SO post (the marked answer): [Quality problems when resizing an image at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231817/quality-problems-when-resizing-an-image-at-runtime)
to work with.

The photo I'm testing on is taken on my LG G3, so the quality is pretty crisp.. if that helps.

Comment: Are you sure that you're not getting the thumbnail instead of the full image?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem a few month ago. May be this this is the answer that you aro looking for. Give a try:

```
BitmapFactory.Options op = new BitmapFactory.Options();
op.inScaled = false;
Bitmap a = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath.getAbsolutePath(), op);
```