# How to avoid image from distort in Android?

Tags: android, bitmap, base64, image-resizing

I want to reuse size of bitmap when I send to server as base64. For example, original image size is 1.2 MB so I have to resize it to 50KB (server limit side). [The way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4837803/5241603) make image distort sometimes. I have read [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231817/quality-problems-when-resizing-an-image-at-runtime)] and [[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821488/bad-image-quality-after-resizing-scaling-bitmap)], but it didn't help.

The problem is some image become distort after resize.

Here is my code:

```
private String RescaleImage(String bitmap, int size) {
    try {
        if ((float) bitmap.getBytes().length / 1000 <= Constants.PROFILE_IMAGE_LIMITED_SIZE) {
            return bitmap;
        } else {
            //Rescale
            Log.d("msg", "rescale size : " + size);
            size -= 1;
            bitmap = BitmapBase64Util.encodeToBase64(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(decodeBase64(bitmap), size, size, false));
            return RescaleImage(bitmap, size);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

encodingToBase64:

```
public static String encodeToBase64(Bitmap image) {
    Log.d(TAG, "encoding image");

    String result = "";
    if (image != null) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
        result = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

        Log.d(TAG, result);
        return result;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Image is cropped before resize. Size after cropped is 300 x 300

My question is:

**How to reuse image size to 50KB, keep same ratio and avoid distort?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I update my code and it work better now.

-- FixED --

Instead of resize the bitmap string continuously, I use the orignal bitmap that is used before resize.

```
private String RescaleImage(String bitmap, Bitmap origin_bitmap, int size) {
    try {
        if ((float) bitmap.getBytes().length / 1000 <= Constants.PROFILE_IMAGE_LIMITED_SIZE) {
            return bitmap;
        } else {
            //Rescale
            Log.d("msg", "rescale size : " + size);
            size -= 1;
            bitmap = BitmapBase64Util.encodeToBase64(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(origin_bitmap, size, size, false));
            return RescaleImage(bitmap, origin_bitmap, size);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

Also, use this code when decode to reuse distortion. [Bad image quality after resizing/scaling bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4822358/5241603).

If there are better fix, I always welcome in order to improve.

Answer (score 0):

You pass the the same width and height in `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(decodeBase64(bitmap), size, size, false)`. Unless your bitmaps are squares you have to specify the right widht and height, otherwise your image gets distorted based on the original aspect ratio. I think something like this would work:

```
Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(decodeBase64(bitmap);
bitmap = BitmapBase64Util.encodeToBase64(scaledBitmap, scaledBitmap.getWidth(), size.getHeight(), false);
```

If you need compression to reduce the size use this [Edit: You have done this]:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream); 
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

Comment: Agree this idea. But how to make its size lower or equal 50KB?

Comment: With Bitmaps you can't. the bigger the resolution the bigger the size. If you have to compress your image use this `ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();`

Comment: Actually, I compressed it already when encoded. See my update.

Comment: I see, the problem might come from `decodeBase64(bitmap)` or using the `size` as width and height.

Comment: `RescaleImage(bitmap, size);` looks dodgy too. I would expect `RescaleImage(bitmap, width, height);` there too. What happens if you apply your logic to a square bitmap (100*100 or similar)? Does that get distorted?

Comment: Image is cropped before resize. After crop, image size is 300 x 300.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147353/discussion-between-k-sopheak-and-endre-borcsok).